# FixedJoint error in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

I get the following error every time I run the code:

error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Joint.breakForce'

```
Joint.breakForce = Mathf.Infinity;
```

How can I properly write this? I want to set the break force to Mathf.Infinity to render the joint unbreakable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with my script; An object reference is required to access non-static member](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110362/issue-with-my-script-an-object-reference-is-required-to-access-non-static-membe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to reference the object

```
private FixedJoint joint;
void Start()
{
    joint = GetComponent<FixedJoint>();//assuming the joint and script components are attached to same gameobject.
    joint.breakForce = Mathf.Infinity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `Joint` is a class. If you have an object called `Joint`, rename it to lowercase `joint`, since that is the proper naming style in C#. Your code then should become:

```
joint.breakForce = Mathf.Infinity;
```

Comment: And how do I properly write this? `FixedJoint.breakForce = Mathf.Infinity;`

Comment: Because I get error CS0103: The name `joint' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Because there should be an object called 'joint', which you want to make unbreakable, but here you're trying to set the break force to a class called 'Joint' which doesn't make sense. Adding more context code into your question may help resolving the issue.

Comment: My other question and what I want to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33389802/glitch-issue-with-fixedjoint-in-unity?noredirect=1#comment54571961_33389802

Comment: Also, read the comments in the other question.

Comment: Anyway I'd like to see the full code from the moment the object you're having trouble with is instantiated/retreived in your method, not just a link to another question. I won't be able to help you otherwise.